# XCode - Auto layout error each time re-open project

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, xcode6, ios-autolayout

I've created a project using XCode "Version 6.0.1 (6A317)". I've used auto layout and size classes too.

The problem seems to be an awkward one. Whenever i reopen the project, auto layout constraints changes to something else.

e.g a `UIButton` has constraints for "width, bottom, leading & trailing". All is set correctly. But now i close the project and reopen,, that button's all layout constraints are misplaced and gives me warning about misplacement of buttons.

Anyone else ran in to the same issue?
Please help. Thanks,.

Comment: don't know if its relevant but I had a problem when I accidently opened my storyboard in `6.0.1` ands `5.1.1` refused to open it as few new constraints are added in `6.0.1`

Comment: @geekay I'm not using older version. This problem happens in latest XCode 6.0.1 only !!. That's y i;m confused. Thinking to fill a bug report now.

Comment: same thing happened to me! I opened a different question for it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595611/how-to-fix-xcode-layout-issue. Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: I'm afraid, no. But i managed to keep this errors low by redoing those constraints.