# How to fix Xcode layout issues?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am designing layout for iPhones so I chose "wCompact and hAny" size class for it. I fix the constraints and there is no issue while I am running it. But every time I close the Xcode reopen the project, there comes multiple issues with the constraints. As shown in the picture.

[image]

I fixed the issue updating the frame as per constraint. Choosing the first option in the picture below.  But again when I reopen the Xcode, same issue arises over and over again. I have to redo it all the time. What's causing this problem and how to resolve it?

[image]

Comment: You have a _lot_ of issues so you need to fix _all_ of them. Choose Editor > Resolve Auto Layout Issues > All Views > Update Frames. Does that solve it?

Comment: No. I chose the view controller that's showing the issue. But the that option is deactivated in menu. Only "Reset to suggested constraints" and "Clear Constraints" option is highlighted.

Comment: Choose Update Constraints and check Apply to all views in container and then click Fix Misplacement. If it doesn't work, you can share your storyboard file.

Comment: That's what I do and it fixes the issues. But my question is, why the same issue arise when I reopen the project in xCode. I have to refix the issue again n again. I am surprised that nobody else is getting this issue here, or isn't reporting. Cuz couple of my friends also getting same issue on their project.

Comment: I see similar problem, sometimes when I open the project, it suggests the label y position should change from 167 to 166, width should be 21 instead of 22, something like that, but not something so dramatic in your picture.

Comment: Are you using size classes? In particular, are you using particular size classes? Perhaps you need to make this change in the appropriate size class. The truth is I'm just guessing; I've never seen this issue...

Comment: Yes I am using the size class as I have stated in the question. "wCompact and hAny". And I fix the issue in the same size class.

Comment: @gabbler I face similar problems as well.

Comment: Yes, I fixed it by updating Frames. It happens but not very often.

Comment: I too faced the same issues, as these are just warnings..i just ignored..

Comment: to have a look share you storyboard or nib somewhere

Comment: Please check which size class is selected, when you open the Xcode every time. Also Make sure you make all changes in the appropriate size class.

Comment: Just ignore them. Even if the storyboard does not have the actual view that will be render the device gets the right positions for each view dynamically according to your constrains

Comment: Please check the size class in storyboard when you reopen your project on xCode. Some times it happens that when you reopen your xCode size class in storyboard changes. Also if it's in wAny hAny change it to wCompact hAny and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score -1):

that is problem about outside container view's position constraints was not right.
try to find it and fix it.

when the view did load, you can find the problem in the LLDB Console.